# SSH VScode to ec2 instance AWS Linux

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I am trying to connect to an AWS ec2 instance from my MacBook Pro using VScode. I am able to connect to the ec2 instance through the terminal by cd'ing to the `Downloads` folder (where my key pair `.pem` file is) using the command

```shell
ssh -i "Key-Pair.pem" ec2-user@ec2-**-***-**-***.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

My terminal shows me

```shellsession
[ec2-user@ip-***-**-**-*** ~]$
```

However, when trying to connect to the AWS instance from VScode I get the error

```
Load key "/Users/****/Downloads/Key-Pair.pem": Operation not permitted
ec2-user@**.***.**.***: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down
```

It seems as though my key pair `.pem` file is not able to authenticate with the AWS instance.

For reference this is what my config file looks like for this instance

```
Host PM.ByBit.SMM
    Hostname **.***.**.***
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile /Users/****/Downloads/Key-Pair.pem
```

Help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A google search using the error you posted returned this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74258898/6535165

Comment: Thank you, moving the .pem file to ~/.ssh has solved the issue. Weird that when the file was in /Downloads and the the Identityfile was located to that directory that the connection was failing. Thanks